# Constructing a set of integers coprime with $n$ with a certain property

Tags: number-theory

Hello what I would like to do is take a fixed arbitrary integer $n$ (it is safe to assume it is fairly large if need be) and construct a set of integers, $P_i$, which are all coprime with $n$ such that if I subtract any two numbers on the list I get a number that is also coprime with $n$

A trivial example would be $n=15$, $P_1 = 4$, $P_2 = 8$.   So both $P_1$ and $P_2$ are coprime with $15$ and and there difference is 4 which is also coprime with 15.

Basically I would like to estimate the maximum possible size of such a list.  Note that the case when $n$ is a prime is trivial because we can take every integer from $1$ to $n-1$

Any information you have about this would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Let $p$ be the smallest prime factor of $n$.  Then you can get $p-1$ numbers, for example
$$1,2,3,\ldots,p-1\ ,$$
but you can't get any more since any $p$ integers must include either one which is a multiple of $p$ or two which are congruent modulo $p$.

Comment: @Ethan Certainly there will be other possible lists.  But the OP's question was only about the maximum size of the list, not about the specific elements.

Comment: Alright, nice answer took me a couple seconds to think it through. +1

Comment: Got it, thanks for your answer, it unfortunately doesn't do me much good because most of the time this will be a pretty small list. I may just have to assume n to be prime which is something I was trying to avoid

Answer (score 1):

Certainly all the numbers $\{a_i\}$ have to be a different residue class $\bmod p_1$, where $p_1$ is the smallest prime factor of $n$, to avoid having any of the differences $(a_j-a_i) \equiv 0 \bmod p_1$ since then $(a_j-a_i) \mid n$. So $p_1-1$ is a maximum size for your set, for example $\{1,7,13,19\}$ when $n=25$.

Comment: Maybe you should prove why you can get $p_1 - 1$ numbers, possibly Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @user202729 added a bit of justification.